# Can the command completion for `cd` be modified to only show directories and ignore files?

Tags: bash, ls, autocomplete, cd-command

When I am in a directory in bash, and I press `cd` <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it shows everything in the directory as a possibility. (`Show all 1000 possibilities?`) This is really cumbersome when I am in a directory with lots of regular files and relatively few directories.

**So, is it possible to make the choices for autocompletion of `cd` to only include directories?**

I know I can get a directory listing within a directory by doing

`ls -d */`

but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

I am using *CentOS 6.6 Final*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add

```
complete -d cd
```

in your `~/.bashrc` (or other bash configuration file).

Comment: it works! thanks. I had to type `bash` after to reload my `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: That's interesting. This is the default behavior on my Debian install, but typing `complete` doesn't show `-d cd` or anything like it. Apparently it's been done in some other way here.

Comment: @TomZych There is popular [bash completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) script, it is very likely that your distro installed it by default.

Comment: To re-read `~/.bashrc` type `. ~/.bashrc`. This may it does not start a sub-shell.

Comment: @richard One can also just re-type/paste this command in current interactive shell.

Comment: @richard so typing `bash` again starts a sub-shell? good to know!

Comment: Yes try typing quit, or look at results of `pstree -h`.

Comment: In the rare cases that you have commands in `.bashrc` that cannot be safely run more than once (e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:/blah` would create extra `/blah`s), then you can also run `exec bash` (or `exec $SHELL` to be more portable). This creates a new shell, but does not leave the old shell hanging around in the process tree.

Answer (score 5):

This *should* be happening automatically on a typical install on many distros.
If it is not, you're probably missing the `bash-completion` package:

- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install bash-completion`
- Arch: `sudo pacman -S bash-completion`

Comment: On Debian Bullseye 11.2, this is the default for all user EXEPT `root`. In order to have the same behaviour on user `root`, you have to manually edit your `bashrc` file to source the `bash_completion` package.