# Make bash understand I want to complete a directory name after "cd"

Tags: bash, directory, autocomplete, cd-command

How to get `bash` to auto-complete `cd` commands only with directory names and ignore filenames (just as CMD on Windows)

Example:

I'm in

```
/some/folder/
```

I have

```
-rwxr-xr-x filesharp
-rwxr-xr-x fileshallow
-rwxr-xr-- file
drwxrwxrwx files
```

I want that when I enter `cd f<tab>`, `bash` auto-completes it as `cd /home/dds/files` not having to enter `s` manually: there's only a single directory matching my prefix.

EDIT: Solution found up to this point (add `autocomplete -d cd` to `.bashrc`)

Also would be great to have the "scroll trough names", available on Windows, when each time I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get the completion for a single file (or folder) matching the prefix I entered.

Comment: Yes it can be done. My system is set up this way, I am not sure how. I am using Debian, I have package `bash-completion` installed (I suspect that it is responsible).

Comment: [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186422/can-the-command-completion-for-cd-be-modified-to-only-show-directories-and-ign)

Answer (score 0):

(This is a duplicate of the question linked by Nahuel in comment)

As the link's answer says, write in your `~/.bashrc`

```
complete -d cd
```

You can run the command to see the effect right away.

(For its powerful shell features, I like to use `zsh`.)

Comment: If it's a duplicate you should mark it as such